# Ambiguous use of 'init' with CFStringTransform and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string

When trying to build the sample project of [BonMot](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot),

```
let theCFMutableString = NSMutableString(string: myString) as CFMutableString
CFStringTransform(theCFMutableString, UnsafeMutablePointer<CFRange>(nil), kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName, false)
```

I get this error on the `CFStringTransform` line

```
Ambiguous use of 'init'
```

The Xcode 8 project uses Swift 3

Comment: is everything working for you now? Please file a bug against [BonMot](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot/issues) if you are still seeing issues on the latest version. Judging by the date of your post, however, I'm guessing you were running into this in BonSpecialGenerator.swift, which was later updated to Swift 3, and doesn't exist at all since BonMot 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 2, pointer types conformed to `NilLiteralConvertible`, allowing a non-optional pointer type to represent a null pointer. Therefore when you did

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<CFRange>(nil)
```

the compiler was actually using the `init(_ other: COpaquePointer)` initialiser of `UnsafeMutablePointer`, as `COpaquePointer` is `NilLiteralConvertible` and can therefore represent a null pointer.

However in Swift 3 ([SE-0055](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md)), pointer types no longer conform to `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`. Rather than allowing a non-optional pointer type to represent a null pointer, this is now simply done with optionals, where `nil` means a null pointer.

Therefore you can just pass `nil` directly into the `range` parameter of `CFStringTransform`, as it expects a `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFRange>!`:

```
CFStringTransform(theCFMutableString, nil, kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName, false)
```