# Syntax error when creating unsafe generic pointer (Generic parameter 'Pointee' could not be inferred)

Tags: swift, generics

I am building wrapper around `GObject`, and I am trying to create generic pointer for it

```
class Object<T> {
    internal(set) var object = UnsafeMutablePointer(nil)
}
```

but I am getting this error

[image]

The type should be resolved in my opinion, however compiler complains. Do I create this pointer correctly? Is this just compiler bug, or I have done this wrong?

---

Edit
I tried every syntax that came to my mind, like this:

```
class Object<T> {
    internal(set) var object: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?

    init() {
        object = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(nil)
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work, because compiler somehow can't resolve the type

[image]

Comment: By passing `nil` in the constructor, the struct cannot infer the type. Just type `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(nil)`. This should work

Comment: Before I asked the question I tried this as well. It doesn't work neither.

Comment: Only *optional* pointers can be `nil` in Swift 3, e.g. `var object: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>? = nil` – But it would be interesting to know how the pointer is used in your code.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Ambiguous use of 'init' with CFStringTransform and Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39548291/2976878). Although in your case, you can just leave it as `internal(set) var object: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?` – it will by default be initialised to `nil`.

Comment: @martin-r, here you can find the source code
https://github.com/swift-gtk/SwiftGTK
So you can see the usage, nothing special, I am just experimenting with bridging.

Answer (score 0):

The type declaration in your second approach is correct. The error message "Ambiguous use" comes because `UnsafeMutablePointer` has two initializer candidates that accept a `nil`: one that takes an `OpaquePointer?` and one that takes an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?`.

In your case, you should simply assign `nil`:

```
init() {
    object = nil
}
```

You can also do this right in the property definition, no need to do it in `init`.